# How to show classification maps for land cover types prediction using convolutional neural networks

Tags: maps, classification, prediction

I have trained a convolutional neural network to classify six different land cover classes using 50*50 patches. Now, my next task is to use this model to classify 500*500 image containing these six land cover types and display my map. Please can anyone help me write code for this task?